# Mule Anypoint studio Kafka Connector - Consumer is not able to receive messages

Tags: mule, kafka-consumer-api, mule-studio, mule-component

Mule application (Any Point Studio application) is consuming messages published by API application through Kafka ,

But Mule(Any Point Studio) Kafka Consumer is not able to receive messages. Every time i have stop start the application to consume messages ,
even we do that we are receiving old messages including new message,

Using Mule 3.9 Version, kafka-client ‎0.10.0.0

I tried adding some properties to consumer.properties file, like poll.

```
Consumer.Properties having below code,
group.id=user
auto.offset.reset=earliest
enable.auto.commit=false

Consumer.Properties having below code,

group.id=user
```

In Any point studio flow , Kafka Connector [Consumer] -> Given topic name as customer_data, partitions as 1 . Haven't provided any Offset

I expected the Consumer should read message with out re-starting application and older messages shouldn't receive again

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that mule only manages offset if your enable.auto.commit is true.
Keeping it true is bad idea since it would commit offset even if your muleflow will be failing. So you did a right thing by disabling it.

Here comes the problem - after enable.auto.commit=false you basically suppose to manage offset yourself. I am having similar problem and considering creating custom class that will explicitly call sync() after mule flow executed successfully.